# How do I turn off Inspect Element (Q) in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I got the new Firefox 12 and I hit the "Inspect Element (Q)". I'm used to hitting "Inspect" and getting FireBug, now I get the Firefox inspection tool. It looks nice, but how do I turn it off – not disable it, but stop inspecting the current page?

I have to close the tab, when working on a large web application, sign back in and re-setup everything I was testing to get back to a normal view. Big waste of time.

Comment: Closing the Inspection window does not work. Nor Escape key like the FF inspection page says to do. Stuck open.

Comment: It got stuck open for me to. I couldn't figure out how to close it, but when I restarted Firefox, it was gone—and I was able to open and close it properly after that. Strange. (FF 17)

Answer (score 6):

Looks like [SocialCouch](http://www.socialcouch.com/remove-native-inspect-element-context-menu-in-firefox-10/) has a good guide on it, in which they say that:

On Firefox 13 you also need to change `extensions.firebug.hideDefaultInspector`. to true (you need firebug installed for this). This is found on the `about:config` page.

Answer (score 2):

FF 14 re-enables the inspector (just for fun I guess) even if you have disabled it before.

To disable change the following in about:config

```
devtools.inspector.enabled                 false
devtools.styleinspector.enabled            false
extensions.firebug.hideDefaultInspector    true
```

Answer (score 1):

I disabled many of my add-ons, including the Web Developer and FireBug. Thought i saw some post where they may cause an issue, but i can not find the pot again.

Plus i removed several older add-ons that i no longer needed or used, or were out of date.

The Inspection tool now works correctly, I can hit the "X" or Escape to close the thml inspection tools.

I also re enabled Webdeveploer Addon and Firebug, and the Inspection tool is still working. So, some add-on was not playing nicely with the FF inspection tool.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with inspect element in Firefox 12 is that if you press the type of view button again it returns the page to normal regardless of whether it is HTML 3D view or style.

Comment: What is the type of view button?

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions to disable things in about:config doesn't work on Linux w/ newer builds 48+. Inspectors and all still popup with everything dissabled.

But with this extension you can disable shortcuts:
Keybinder: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/keybinder/
(Note above is to replace Customizable Shortcuts by Tim Taubert, which is no longer developed/removed)

Config -> Shortcut mapping -> change > (find shortcut, disable).

Comment: this is good option. if you desire more control over context menu, consider Menu Wizard -- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/

Answer (score 0):

At least in Firefox 12 you can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to close the window.